# How encode Audio file and save it with unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, encode, assetbundle

I want to encode some type of file from my assetbundle and save those files to my path. I use this code for encoding Texture2D file to ".jpg" and save it:

```
(my assetbundle method work fine)
texTmp = (Texture2D) Instantiate (assetRequest.asset);
SaveSaveToJpg(texTmp);
```

and save with:

```
void SaveToJpg(Texture2D texture)
{
byte[] bytes = texture.EncodeToPNG();
File.WriteAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "/"+ texture.name + ".jpg", bytes);
}
```

So in Unity documentation, I saw how can encode the .mp4 file, but how can I encode the Audio file and save it with unity?

**Edit:**
I use https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063#file-savwav-cs class, but is there any unity official method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SavWav Script](https://gist.github.com/darktable/2317063)

```
public AudioClip myAudio;

SavWav.Save(Application.persistentDataPath + "/audio.wav", myAudio);
```

Comment: thanks, is this olny way ? is there any unity native class or method?